# MiniKube on EC2, External DNS lookup failing (say speech.googleapis.com) from within Pod

Tags: amazon-ec2, minikube

I have installed MiniKube on EC2. The Micro-services are talking to each other. However, when one of them tries to call an external Service say - speech.googleapis.com, I am encountering the below error in the Pod:

```
2019-06-04 06:59:46 [grpc-default-executor-0] [WARN ] [i.g.i.ManagedChannelImpl$NameResolverListenerImpl.onError 1323] : [Channel<1>: (speech.googleapis.com:443)] Failed to resolve name. status=Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=Unable to resolve host speech.googleapis.com, cause=java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.UnknownHostException: speech.googleapis.com
        at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver.resolveAll(DnsNameResolver.java:399)
        at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$Resolve.resolveInternal(DnsNameResolver.java:269)
        at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$Resolve.run(DnsNameResolver.java:225)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: speech.googleapis.com
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1281)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1193)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1127)
        at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$JdkAddressResolver.resolveAddress(DnsNameResolver.java:624)
        at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver.resolveAll(DnsNameResolver.java:367)
        ... 5 more
}
```

Same works perfectly on Google Kubernetes Engine.

Comment: On GKE it worked because it was google api. If you want to use external API you should configure your network settings. Do you have any AWS API Gateway or VPC between GKE and EC2?

Comment: Thanks @PjoterS. Actually, I deployed my micro-services on MiniKube on EC2 - faced this issue. Then re-deployed the same micro-services on GKE - where it worked fine. There is no connection between GKE & EC2. Just that I faced an issue with Minikube on EC2.

Comment: were you able to get this working? I have the same issue.